# Please Explain the Grammer Pattern and use of 見てんの

Tags: grammar, usage

Studying Terrace House subtitles. In Episode 1, someone says:

どういう気持ちで見**てんの**？

(please correct the following assumptions in case I'm wrong)

I understand どういう to be どう言う or "What would you say of"
気持ちで I understand to be like "your feelings of"
見て I understand to mean "seeing"
の is a more gentle(feminine sounding) question marker I think.

so literal "What would you say of your feelings about seeing the show"

but I'm uncertain of how ん is being used here grammatically. Is it akin to something like "tell me the truth" or "be frank about this".

so literal "What would you **honestly** say of your feelings about seeing the show?"

Like 泳げないんです。"To be honest, I can't swim."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: どういう気持ちで = "with what kind of feeling" (で is "with" here). So the original sentence means "How do you feel while you're seeing it?"